# How do you expose a C++ class in the V8 Javascript Engine so it can be created using new?

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

The [official examples](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html) of exposing a Point class seem to assume that there will be a fixed number of instances of it in your program. It is not clear how new instances are allocated in the C++ code, when *new* is called in Javascript.

How would you expose a class that can have multiple instances? For example, an Image class:

```
var img1 = new Image( 640, 480 );
var img2 = new Image( 1024, 768 );

img1.clear( "red" );
img2.clear( "black" );
```

Answer (score 30):

This is the best [blog post I could find on exposing C++ objects to V8 Javascript](http://web.archive.org/web/20150217015842/http://create.tpsitulsa.com/blog/2009/01/29/v8-objects). It goes into deeper detail and breaks it down into smaller steps with code snippets. Be warned: the code snippets have little inconsistencies and it took me several reads to understand. Reading my brief summary beforehand may help:

1. **Objects must be wrapped in V8 templates.** Note: The Google sample uses ObjectTemplates, but the author explains why he prefers FunctionTemplates.

   1. Create a FunctionTemplate. Instances of this template have an internal field to store the memory address of the C++ object. They also get the class' accessor methods.
   2. Make a function wrapObject() that will wrap a C++ object in one of these FunctionTemplates.
2. **The constructor must also be wrapped in a (different) V8 template.** A different template is used to avoid unwanted recursion. (A method of combining both templates into one is described at the end of the blog post.)

   1. Create another FunctionTemplate. This template simply connects the JavaScript global scope (where `new` will be called from) to the C++ constructor.
   2. Make the method that the template will call. This method actually uses the C++ `new` operator and calls the C++ class constructor. It then wraps the object by calling the wrapObject() method created in step 1.2.

---

Now, the memory allocated in step 2.2 must be `delete`'d some time. **Update:** The next blog entry, "[Persistent Handles](http://web.archive.org/web/20140727091841/http://create.tpsitulsa.com/blog/2009/01/31/persistent-handles/)," covers this in detail.

My notes on the [actual code alluded to in these blog posts](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~alex.iskander/create/trunk/annotate/head%3A/Script/Source/Environments/V8/V8Context.cpp):

- The `wrapPoint()` method in the blog is actually analogous to the `unwrap()` method in the actual code; *not* `wrap()`
- To find other common points between the code, search for: `SetInternalFieldCount(0`, `constructorCall`
- The actual code seems to do memory management by using the MakeWeak() method to set a callback method that does the cleanup.

Comment: the blog post you linked at the top is dead

Answer (score 3):

Here is a helper i wrote a while back that makes exposing and dealing with contexts in v8 pretty easy.
Hope it helps.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2796/binding-c-and-v8-javascript-from-google/2797#2797

Answer (score -12):

I don't know how to achieve this in V8 Js engine exactly, but as in the Python world, you can just do as following.
your Image class:

```
class Image
{
public:
    Image(int w, int h);
    int Width(void) const;
};
```

write some wrapper functions and expose these functions to the Js world:

```
Image* Image_New(int w, int h) { return new Image(w, h); }
void Image_Delete(Image* pImage) { delete pImage; }
int Image_Width(const Image* pImage) { return pImage->Width(); }
```

add the following codes to your js file:

```
var Image = function (w, h) {
    this.image = new Image(w, h);
    this.Width = function() {
        return Image_Width(this.image);
    };
};
```

and now you can get you code work.
Additionally, the codes above haven't take the Garbage collection mechanism into consideration, so pay some special attention to it.Sorry for my borken English!

Comment: What about exporting of functions defined?

Comment: Yes, python has a great API for this. That's why V8 is so confusing! Why is there no V8::FunctionTemplate::SetClassAllocator( AllocateFn, FreeFn )?

Comment: v8 is way faster then python though